# Can't unistall Oracle Database 11g

Tags: windows-7, oracle-11g

I'm having huge issues trying to delete Oracle Database 11g. I tried the OUI (Oracle Universal Installer) but it didn't work. (It showed a warning telling me that you should use deinstall, but that didn't work either.)

After that, I tried deleting the folders manually and this time it told me that I couldn't because some folders or files were being used.

It's really frustrating. Now I can neither delete nor install a database.

Note: I followed the steps that tell you to stop the services and remove the keys using regedit.

Comment: I've never been able to fully remove an oracle instance. I always end up rebuilding the system instead. what problems did you have with the deinstall tool? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/deinstall.htm

Comment: I started the deinstall tool but after that it shows me : "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Error - Assertion Failed" .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 then follow these steps:

1. Delete the Oracle path from  environment variables from your machine.
2. Delete oracle registry.

   - Press Win+R type regedit and then navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ORACLE and right click and delete.
   - Next navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
   - Delete all the Oracle services and directories
3. Restart the system
4. Now go to C:\App and delete all the Oracle folders and also delete the Oracle files from Program Files

If it gives an error, restart your PC and try deleting again.